# Is there a way to add microdata to an image referenced in CSS?

Tags: html, css, microdata, schema.org

I am attempting to add itemprop="image" for a corporation's logo (as shown here: http://www.schema.org/Corporation), but I am using the Gantry Logo plugin from the Gantry framework for Wordpress. As a result, the image is actually loaded by a reference in CSS, and not using the HTML  tag.

Unfortunately, it seems that the itemprop="image" can only be added to that tag, as that is where it grabs the URL from.

Can anybody think of a way around this without attempting to hide a logo on the site and place the tag on it?

(The site I am specifically referring to is http://www.bpsresolver.com for reference.)

Answer (score 2):

> "Can anybody think of a way around this without attempting to hide a
>   logo on the site and place the tag on it?"

That's exactly what needs to be done.
The way to do it is to open the source for this Gantry Logo plugin and find the logo's `<a id='logo'></a>` that the css refers to and change it to `<img src='yourimage.jpg'/>`  I usually use WindowsGrep to find id='logo' or whatever it may be in your case.

But to answer your question: "Is there a way to add microdata to an image referenced in CSS?" - No :)

Comment: Thanks Miro! The solution I found in the end was a modification of what you recommended, which I'll show below...

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing to fix it was going to the logo.php plugin located in /plugins/gantry/widgets/. At the bottom of that file is where the `<a>` tag is that miro mentioned.

Instead of removing it and replacing it (since it had a number of other CSS properties attached that needed to stay the same), I simply added the `<img>` tag in between the `<a>` tags, and changed the CSS that referred to the image from `background: url(url_to_image);` to `background: transparent;`.

Lastly, I wrapped the whole thing in a `<div>` tag which I used to indicate the scope, and placed `itemprop` inside `<img>`.